# Publication on the virulence of diseases which are likely transfered by used needles from addicts

Tags: virus, infectious-diseases, addiction

There are many (work)places, where one could get pricked accidentally by a used needle which was thrown away by a careless drug addict.

Which diseases are typically present on used needles is discussed in "[Publication on the contamination of used needels by addicts](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/19959/publication-on-the-contamination-of-used-needels-by-addicts)".

In this question I am looking for publications on the virulence of the diseases which are typically transferred, if a person gets pricked accidentally by a needle from an addict.

Comment: The risk of "needlestick injuries" is high in many more jobs than some may believe. Working on the railways (on the tracks) in the past put me at risk in some places. The risk of HIV is one infection which worries those affected, but there are others so this is a good question.

Comment: Loosely related: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/19613

Comment: HIV is the last disease I would worry about from needle stick injury unless the needle was freshly used. HIV is very fragile and can't survive open air exposure. Of more concern would be HBV, which is very hardy and can survive exposure for quite some time. And that's the problem any such study looking at discarded needles would face. It would almost be more of a measure of needle age than actual contamination.

Comment: I would agree @CareyGregory but a lot of people who are not aware of the fragility of HIV still worry about it.